# Wordpress escaping special characters unnecessarily in my blog titles, how can I prevent this behaviour?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code in a blade template file in a Wordpress Bedrock website. In this section a title happens to contain the "-" character. When it is appended to the title like this it works: "-title". However, when there is a space between it ("- title") gets escaped as –

Of course I could use something like html_entity_decode to fix it in this one instance but I want to prevent it happening at other places in the website. At least for stuff like this that is not a user input. Is there any way to define this in a Wordpress Bedrock application?

````php
  @foreach($slides_links as $link)
          {{ var_dump($link['title']) }}
          <a href="{{ $link['link'] }}" title="{{ $link['title'] }}">
            <div class="group mb-6 border-b border-red-200 pb-6 flex flex-row hover:text-red-100">
              <div class="flex flex-col flex-1">
                <h3 class="text-lg">{{ $link['title'] }}</h3>
                <p>{{ $link['description'] }}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="flex items-center">
                <p class="rounded-button flex group-hover:bg-red-100">&rarr;</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        @endforeach
    ```
````

Comment: `&#8211;` _is_ the numeric entity for an en dash, so how is this actually a problem? Or are you saying that you _see_ `&#8211;` in the rendered output? That would mean that HTML escaping happened _twice_ for some reason.

Comment: `{{ }}` escapes the input data, `{{{ }}}` doesn't. Using the latter could superficially "fix" your issue - but you should rather go and investigate, why your title apparently contained the numeric entity to begin with already. Because it sounds like what _is_ getting escaped here, is the `&` that contained.

Comment: @CBroe
I did some more digging today and as far as I can see blog post content is being automatically filtered so that it does allow this character. And yes I was seeing `&#8211;` in the rendered output. From what I can tell this filter is not being applied in this case, which happened to be a vacancy. The previous developer randomly used `{!! !!}` on some titles/descriptions and on others (like this one) he did not. I figured since it's not an input I'd just escape it and call it a day since I don't want to waste too much time on this. Do you think there is a better solution?

Comment: If you know there won't be any unescaped data in there that would need escaping - then what's wrong with using the `{{{ ... }}}` syntax, three curly braces instead of two?

Comment: Tbh, I thought they did the same thing and `{!! !!}` is already being used everywhere else so I figured I'd follow the project standard. Using exclamation marks also seems a little more clear to me for anyone scanning the code. I usually work with Laravel and I've never seen anyone use `{{{ ... }}}` in any of our applications.

Comment: Okay if they both do the same thing, then it should not matter which one you are using. But the better solution would probably be to try and figure out why the incoming data already appears to have been escaped once at this point - and then _disable_ that. Because otherwise, if that as of yet unexplained "magic" might stop at some point in the future, your system might become vulnerable.